# php - How to remove html tag using regular expression?

Tags: php, regex

value of `$attributes['st_title']` is `<a href="/physical-design-engineers">Physical Design Engineers</a>`

I want to remove `<a href="/physical-design-engineers">` and `</a>`. The final expected output is: `$attributes['st_title'] = Physical Design Engineers`

I am trying as follows:

```
    $pattern[0] = "/<a.[^>]+>/";
    $pattern[1] = '/</a>/';

    $replacement[1] = '';
    $replacement[0] = '';
    $attributes['st_title'] = preg_replace( $pattern, $replacement, $attributes['st_title'] );
```

But it sets `$attributes['st_title']` as empty. Any idea?

Comment: [(;,;)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/283366)

Comment: You want to _strip the tags_?

Comment: Better option ~ [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @mickmackusa got a duplicate in mind?

Comment: They will never stop coming... lost cause.

Comment: @Phil Can only negatively voted questions be delete-voted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want text only from the link, so use [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
echo strip_tags($text);
```

https://eval.in/979039

Answer (score 2):

Use php `strip_tags()`

or

```
preg_replace("/<.*?>/", "", $attributes['st_title']);
```